# Proof that if $\gcd(a,n) = 1$ then $a^k \equiv a^{k \bmod \phi(n)} \pmod {\!n}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, totient-function

From Euler's theorem I know that $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod n$ if $\gcd(a,n) = 1$. However I can't find any proof/explaination of the proof in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider that the the only thing that changes from $a^k$ to $a^{k\!\pmod{\phi(n)}}$ is that the exponents differ by a multiple of $\phi(n)$.

Comment: Since $\Z_n^*$ is a finite set, than we can define a number $y$ such that $a^y \equiv 1 \pmod n$, from euler's theorem we know that $y = \phi(n)$, and this also means that $a^{k \pmod{\phi(n)}} \equiv a^k \pmod n$ for a generic $k$ , since $\phi(n) \mid k$ (?)

Comment: Not quite. And a bit more complicated than I was thinking. We do _not_ know that $y=\phi(n)$. We know that _setting_ $y=\phi(n)$ makes $a^y\equiv 1$, but the converse doesn't hold (for instance, if $a=1$, then _any_ $y$ will work). However, note that if we set $y=\phi(n)$, then elementary exponent properties give us that $a^k=(a^y)^j\cdot a^{k\!\pmod{\phi(n)}}$ for some integer $j$. Applying modulo $\phi(n)$ to this equality and using Euler's theorem gives you your result.

Answer (score 1):

The *key idea* is to use **modular order reduction** on *exponents* as in the Theorem below. We can find *small* exponents $\,e\,$ such that $\,a^{\large \color{#c00}e}\equiv 1\,$ either by [Euler's totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem) or [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) (or by [Carmichael's lambda generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function)), along with obvious roots of $\,1\,$ such as $\,(-1)^2\equiv 1.$

**Theorem** $ \ \ $ Suppose that: $\,\ \color{#c00}{a^{\large e}\equiv\, 1}\,\pmod{\! m}\ $ and $\, e>0,\ n,k\ge 0\,$ are integers. Then

$\qquad\ \ \ \  n\equiv k\pmod{\! \color{#c00}e}\,\Longrightarrow\,a^{\large n}\equiv a^{\large k}\pmod{\!m}.\: $  The converse holds **if** $\:\color{#c00}e = {\rm ord}\,a,\,$ i.e.

$\qquad\ \ \ \  n\equiv k\pmod{\! \color{#c00}e}\,\Longleftarrow\,a^{\large n}\equiv a^{\large k}\pmod{\!m}\  $  and $\, a\,$ has order $\,\color{#c00}e\,$ mod $\,m$

**Proof** $\ $ Wlog $\,n\ge k\,$ so $\,a^{\large n-k} \color{#0a0}{a^{\large k}}\equiv \color{#0a0}{a^{\large k}}\!\iff a^{\large n-k}\equiv 1\iff n\equiv k\pmod{\!e}\,$ by [this Corollary](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242), where we cancelled $\,\color{#0a0}{a^{\large k}}\,$ using $\,a^{\large e}\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, a\,$ is invertible so cancellable (cf. below Remark).

**Corollary** $\ \ \bbox[7px,border:1px solid #c00]{\!\bmod m\!:\,\  \color{#c00}{a^{\large e}\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\, a^{\large n}\equiv a^{\large n\bmod \color{#c00}e}}\,\ $ by $\ n\equiv n\bmod e\,\pmod{\!\color{#c00}e}$

**Remark** $ $ If you are familiar with modular inverses then it is not necessary to restrict to nonnegative powers of $\,a\,$ above since $\,a^{\large e}\equiv 1,\ e> 0\,\Rightarrow\,$  $a$ is invertible by $\,a a^{\large e-1}\equiv 1\,$ so $\,a^{\large -1}\equiv a^{\large e-1}$.